# A static method as a method parameter (as a lambda)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, generic-lambda

I would like to have a constructor of class to have a lambda as a parameter:

```
class MyComboBox : public QComboBox
{
public:
 explicit MyComboBox( const std::function< QString( Flag ) > &readable, QWidget *parent = nullptr );
};
```

I have some flags in a class, which also have a static method:

```
class QgsField
{
  Q_GADGET
  public:
    enum class ConfigurationFlag : int
    {
      Searchable = 1 << 1,
      Readable = 1 << 2,
    };
    Q_ENUM( ConfigurationFlag )
    Q_DECLARE_FLAGS( ConfigurationFlags, ConfigurationFlag )
    Q_FLAG( ConfigurationFlags )

    static QString readableConfigurationFlag( QgsField::ConfigurationFlag flag );
};
```

I am trying to construct MyComboBox:

```
std::function<QString (QgsField::ConfigurationFlag)> readable = [](QgsField::ConfigurationFlag flag) {return QgsField::readableConfigurationFlag(flag);};
QComboBox *cb = new MyComboBox<QgsField::ConfigurationFlag>(readable, parent );
```

This fails:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "QgsFlagCheckableComboBoxQgsField::ConfigurationFlag::QgsFlagCheckableComboBox(std::__1::function<QString (QgsField::ConfigurationFlag)>&, QWidget*)

1. Is there a way to pass the static method directly without going through a lambda (by definition the base class can change)?
2. Why is it currently failing?

Comment: Taking `std::function` by (non const) reference is strange (and disallow to take temporary one such as one created by lambda), by value or by const reference or even by r-value reference seems better.

Comment: you say lambda but then the constructor takes a `std::function`. It is a common misunderstanding that you need to use `std::function` to pass functions as parameter or that it would be good to do so per se, both isnt quite true

Comment: `explicit QgsFlagCheckableComboBox<Flag>` looks like a constructor but it is not. 

Comment: @ChristopherYeleighton why is it not? what should it be?

Comment: The name of the constructor must be the same as the name of the class.

Comment: oops ;) I fixed this and switched to a const ref. Thanks for the pointer, but the problems stays...

Comment: @idclev463035818 di you have any reference to some documentation or can explain a bit more?

Comment: @Denis Rouzaud The Flag type and the QgsField::ConfigurationFlag type are the same types? Can you compile this code?:
`std::function<QString (QgsField::ConfigurationFlag)> readable = [](QgsField::ConfigurationFlag flag) {return QgsField::readableConfigurationFlag(flag);};
const std::function< QString( Flag ) > &readable2 = readable;`